# How to get a Clean String in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

i have a long String. With some German characters and lots of new lines tabs ect..
In a Selectbox user can select a text, on change i do

```
document.getElementById('text').value=this.value;
```

But this fails. I just get a `"unterminated string literal"` as error in JavaScript.

I think i should clean the string.

How can i do it in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think the string value is the problem here, I think there is some pure syntax error in your script.

Comment: syntax error? but why do i get a unterminated string literal ?

Comment: @streetparade: Using `var x = 'hello;` will probably give you the same error, because the string doesn't end anywhere, as there is no closing apostrophe, i.e. `'`.

Comment: if you want clean the string, just assign the null value.

document.getElementById('text').value="";

Comment: Yes that could be the problem, but in that string there are also some ' or "

Comment: I also tryed escape(string) but it fails

Answer (score 4):

Its not because of that code, there is syntax error somewhere in your javascript file.

For example, in one of your previous question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709934/how-to-handle-a-clicked-link-in-javascript/2709957#2709957)

```
 alert("yes link clicked);
```

You could see, there is `"` is missing after `clicked`, which could cause `unterminated string literal` error. Fix it like

```
 alert("yes link clicked");
```

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot judge from your code, you might want to check what `this` in `this.value` refers to, e.g. using an `alert("debug: " + this.value)` .

Other than that, you might want to use `encodeURI()` for converting umlauts and other special characters to hexadecimal notation. If your page's `content-type` is set to `UTF-8` special characters will then display correctly.